# Java to JavaScript using GWT compiler

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I have some Java code written that I'd like to convert to JavaScript.
I wonder if it is possible to use the GWT compiler to compile the mentioned Java code into JavaScript code **preserving all the names** of the methods, variables and parameters.
I tried to compile it with code optimizations turned off using -draftCompile but the method names are mangled.
If GWT compiler can't do this, can some other tool?

**Update**

The Java code would have dependencies only to GWT emulated classes so the GWT compiler would definitely be able to process it.

**Update 2**

This Java method :

```
public String method()
```

got translated to this JavaScript funciton :

```
function com_client_T_$method__Lcom_client_T_2Ljava_lang_String_2()
```

using the compiler options :

```
-style DETAILED
-optimize 0
-draftCompile
```

So names can't be preserved. But is there a way to control how they are changed?

**Clarification**

Say, for example, you have a sort algorithm written in Java (or some other simple Maths utility). The method sort() takes an array of integers. and returns these integers in an array sorted. Say now, I have both Java and JavaScript applications. I want to write this method once, in Java, run it through the GWT compiler and either keep the method name the same, or have it change in a predictable way, so I can detect it and know how to change it back to sort(). I can then put that code in my JavaScript application and use it. I can also automatically re-generate it if the Java version changes. I have a very good reason technically for this, I understand the concepts of GWT at a high level, I'm just looking for an answer to this point only.

**Conclusion**

The answer to the main question is **NO**.
While method name can be somewhat preserved, its body is not usable. Method calls inside it are scattered throughout the generated file and as such, they can't be used in a JavaScript library which was the whole point of this topic.

Comment: no - you can take a look on the compiler-flags for yourself: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions there is no option to change the compiler behavior in the desired way.

Comment: hav a test with -style PRETTY instead of DETAILED - perhaps this will do it.

Comment: Is the part from the "$" onwards some predictable string, up to the next underline?

Comment: The PRETTY mangles the method name a lot less. For method() I now get $method(). We are getting somewhere with this :).

Comment: I know this is old, but in case anybody else stumbles on it, this looks promising: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/

Comment: To export your library API to JS you must use JsInterop and the compiler flag "-generateJsInteropExports".

Answer (score 10):

Although you can set the compiler to output 'pretty' code, I suggest you write export functions for the classes you want to call from outside your GWT project. I believe somewhere in the GWT documentation it's detailed how to do this, but I couldn't find it so here an example I just created.

```
class YourClass {
    public YourClass() {
        ...
    }

    public void yourMethod() {
        ...
    }

    public static YourClass create() {
        return new YourClass();
    }

    public final static native void export() /*-{
          $wnd.YourClass = function() {
              this.instance = new @your.package.name.YourClass::create()()
          }

          var _ = $wnd.YourClass.prototype;
          _.yourMethod = function() {this.instance.@your.package.name.YourClass::yourMethod()()}
    }-*/;
}
```

**EDIT**

To elaborate, your code will get obfuscated like normal, but thanks to the export function, you can easily reference those functions externally. You *don't* have to rewrite anything from your Java class in JavaScript. You only write the references in JavaScript, so you can do this:

```
var myInstance = new YourClass();
myInstance.yourMethod();
```

Of course you have to call the static export method from somewhere in your GWT app (most likely in your EntryPoint) to make this work.

More info about referencing Java methods from JavaScript:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#methods-fields

Comment: This approach would work assuming I am to keep the Java code. I just need a tool to convert Java method to JavaScript function. To save me the trouble of reimplementing the same algorithm in JavaScript.

Comment: But you could use this method to identify the relevant JavaScript function that the compiler creates.  You asked for a predictable naming scheme, and this is it! `window.YourClass.yourMethod` will point you to the new obfuscated name in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>No - this isn't possible with the GWT compiler, since the GWT compiler is build to generate optimized and very performant JavaScript out of Java.</strike>

The big advantage is, that you can maintain your projekt in Java and compile it with GWT to JavaScript. So there is no need to prevent the variable-names and method-names in the JavaScript result, since all changes and work is done in the JAVA-sources.

Working in the JavaScript-output of GWT just isn't that easy and is really a lot of work!

**Update**:

By a hint of David, I found the Compiler-Option "**-style**". You can have a try with the following options:

```
-style=PRETTY -optimize=0
```

I have no idea if this will really generate "human readable" code. I think it won't, since the GWT framework will still be part of the resulting JavaScript and so it will be difficult to make changes to the JavaScript-result. Have a try and let us know ...

Comment: Why would this answer be downvoted?  It makes perfect sense to me.  Mapping Java semantics to JavaScript is in general going to be an incredibly difficult problem, one that GWT simplifies by targeting web client behaviors etc.

Comment: Not correct. The GWT compiler has the option to optimize, http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions, it also has the option to not compress the output at all (PRETTY or DETAILED). The questioner is saying he wants to know if it's possible, not what are the advantages of using GWT.

Comment: @David the original question offers no description whatsoever about the nature of the Java source code.  GWT only supports a fraction of the standard JDK libraries, for example. In the general case of "just some Java code" that was not necessarily written to target GWT in the first place, chances are GWT would be completely useless.

Comment: The generated compiler output would be used outside of the GWT project so it has to be readable.

Comment: @Pointy I'm assuming the poster understands this, maybe he could clarify. I'm assuming the question is, assuming he has what comes down to Maths, collections and other basic operations (i.e. no widget, input operations, etc), can he translate that code he's written in Java to JavaScript and execute calls against those methods (and wants the function names to be predictable). My downvote was for the answer saying the GWT output must be optimised, that is now clarified and so removed.

Comment: @David: just a comment would have been enough ;) But thanks anyway for your correction.

Comment: The poster has stressed the critical issue, the method names must be preserved, everyone seems to be answering a different question.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I can answer your second question: "If GWT compiler can't do this, can some other tool?"

I am using [Java2Script](http://j2s.sourceforge.net/) for quite a while now, also on quite large projects. Integration with native JavaScript is fine, names are preserved, and after some time one can even match the generated JavaScript (in the browser debugger) with the original Java code with little effort.

Udo

Answer (score 3):

You can "export" your function by writing inline JavaScript that calls it, and there is a tool [gwt-exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter) that does this automatically when you annotate classes and methods with `@Export` and similar.  More information: https://code.google.com/p/gwtchismes/wiki/Tutorial_ExportingGwtLibrariesToJavascript_en